# Can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to solve my error for a few days now but can't find the solution.
Basically, my "profitOfThisTrade" variable apparently returns an array, even though when I print it I only see a float, and I try to compare it to a float. I tried converting the type, changing stuff but nothing works.
Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks

I tried changing the type of the "profitOfThisTrade" variable. I tried only grabbing the first item since apparently it is an array but can't manage to convert it to a float.

```
moneyManagedDF = pd.DataFrame()
currentDate = longsUnderEMA10ROC5.index.strftime("%D")
longsUnderEMA10ROC5["Profit/Loss"] = longsUnderEMA10ROC5["Profit/Loss"].astype(float)
stopForTheDay = 0
stopForThisDay = ""
profitOfThisTrade = 0.0
dailyTarget = 46.0
dailyStop = -124.26
todaysProfit = 0.0
for x in longsUnderEMA10ROC5.index.values:
    if stopForTheDay == 1:
        if stopForThisDay == x:
            break
        elif stopForThisDay != x:
            stopForTheDay = 0
            todaysProfit = 0
    if stopForTheDay == 0:
        moneyManagedDF = moneyManagedDF.append(longsUnderEMA10ROC5.loc[x])
        profitOfThisTrade = longsUnderEMA10ROC5["Profit/Loss"].loc[x].item()
        todaysProfit = todaysProfit + profitOfThisTrade - 3.92
    if (todaysProfit >= dailyTarget) or (todaysProfit <= dailyStop):
        stopForTheDay = 1
        stopForThisDay = x
```

I want to compare profitOfThisTrade and todaysProfit but they don't have the same type.
I get these errors based on when I change the type.
- can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
- The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Please show what is in `profitOfThisTrade`.

Comment: it returns 50.
longsUnderEMA10ROC5 is a dataframe and the "Profit/Loss" column returns floats.